# Timer1 firing immediately

Tags: timers

I'm trying to use Timer1 to get fired once a certain event occurs (about 1ms after the event). Using the timer to get a periodic interrupt works fine, but the very first interrupt fires immediately, rather than after the time I want it.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("start");
}

#define ENTRIES 5
long stack[ENTRIES+1];
int ctr = 0;

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) {
  cli();
  TCNT1 = 50000;

  // if (micros() - stack[0] < 500) return; // work around guard would skip stray 1st interrupt

  stack[ctr++] = micros();

  if (ctr > ENTRIES)
    TIMSK1 &= ~(1 << TOIE1);

  sei();
}

void loop() {
  if (ctr > ENTRIES) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ENTRIES-1; i++) {
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.print(": ");
      Serial.println(stack[i+1] - stack[i]);
    }
    ctr = 0;
  }

  if (!Serial.available()) return;
  char c = Serial.read();
  if (c == 't') {
    Serial.println("testing");

    stack[0] = micros();
    ctr = 1;
    cli(); 

    TCNT1 = 64000; // tick in around 1ms
    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = (1 << CS10); // no prescaler
    TIMSK1 |= (1 << TOIE1); // enable timer overflow interrupt

    sei();
  }
}
```

When you enter `t` on the console it enables the interrupt and - unexpectedly - the timer fires at once. The next one comes after 1ms. A sample output looks like

```
start
testing
0: 8
1: 980
2: 980
3: 980
testing
0: 8
1: 980
2: 980
3: 980
```

Uncommenting the guard yields

```
start
testing
0: 988
1: 972
2: 976
3: 976
```

How can I modify my code (except setting a guard in the beginning of the ISR) so it is triggered once AFTER 1ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interrupt flags are set even without interrupt enable flags, so there is pending overflow that you didin't cleared. And guess what happens after enabling `TOIE1` flag. It gets handled by `ISR`. That's on behalf of Arduino's `analogWrite()` PWM outputs (all timers are up and running in 8bit mode and 1.024ms period).

Btw global interrupts are disabled and reenabled inside of `ISR` handler by hardware so you shouldn't have `cli()` and `sei()` in it.

Also there is another issue - counter mode is preset to 8bits and much bigger prescaler, so the first round is way off.

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("start");
}

#define ENTRIES 5
long stack[ENTRIES+1];
int ctr = 0;

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) {
  TCNT1 = 50000U;
  stack[ctr++] = micros();
  if (ctr > ENTRIES)  TIMSK1 &= ~(1 << TOIE1);
}

void loop() {
  if (ctr > ENTRIES) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ENTRIES-1; i++) {
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.print(": ");
      Serial.println(stack[i+1] - stack[i]);
    }
    ctr = 0;
  }

  if (!Serial.available()) return;
  char c = Serial.read();
  if (c == 't') {
    Serial.println("testing");

    stack[0] = micros();
    ctr = 1;

    TCCR1A = 0;           // you have to change the timer mode before changes
    TCCR1B = 0;           // stop the timer
    TIFR1 |= _BV(TOV1);   // clear the overflow interrupt flag by writing 1 to it
    TCNT1  = 50000U;      // tick in around 1ms / this makes more sense if it's set correctly
    TCCR1B = _BV(CS10);   // no prescaler ?????  REALLY???? this one is prescale by 8
    TIMSK1 |= _BV(TOIE1); // enable timer overflow interrupt
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks like a live saver :-) Too tired now, but will check this tomorrow! Thanks

Comment: That got me wake and it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks also for the info about the interrupt handling :-)

Comment: Ah, and one remark about the remark: The compiler knows that `TCNT1` is an unsigned and will coerce literal numbers correctly. So `TCNT1  = 50000;` works as well.

Comment: @thomaskilian it wasn't about signess. More likely about previous setting by Arduino. You were using the value 64000. Anyway it's better to use unsigned literals especially for bit shifts.

Comment: 64000 < 64k = 64512